# WebGL - Is the gl.useProgram() an expensive call to make?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I'm wondering if this API method used to load a shader program is expensive or not to call?
Im considering making this call per object in my 3D scene.

```
gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
```

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- [this](http://www.pouet.net/topic.php?which=6164) says it's better to use `glUseProgram` than is to `glAttachShader`+`glLinkProgram`
- [this](http://docs.nvidia.com/tegra/Content/GLES2_Perf_Maximize_GPU.html) says that changing shaders is always heavy, but `glUseProgram` is least heavy
- [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html) says it's generally efficient
- [this](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/520288-gluseprogram/) says that moderate and careful use won't become a bottleneck
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683065/behavior-of-uniforms-after-gluseprogram-and-speed) talks a bit about shader-switching performance optimization

So, conslusion: use it moderately. If you don't have much objects - great, if you do - try optimizing shader switching, or reusing shaders multiple times, or use same shader that utilizes branching somehow.

`useProgram` has got medium performance hit. It's not super-light, neither it's super-heavy like `linkProgram` and `compileShader`.

Hope this helps.